# I cannot figure out why my code will not work?

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is wrong with this code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_salary_byname (e_name IN varchar2)

   RETURN NUMBER

   IS salary NUMBER;

   BEGIN

      SELECT salary

      INTO salary

      FROM emp

      WHERE ename= e_name;

      RETURN(salary);

    END;



BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (get_salary_byname('JEFF'));

END
```

The first part of the code works. Oracle successfully creates the function. However, the following errors are received when trying to execute the function with the second part of the code:

```
END *ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"
when expecting one of the following: ; <an identifier>
<a double-quoted-delimited-identifier>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so the title describes the problem you're having. *I cannot figure out why my code will not work* is meaningless; if you could figure out why your code won't work, you wouldn't be asking here. Also, *will not work* is not a useful problem description. In what way does it not work? Do you get an error? If so, what is the exact error message? If not, does it produce the wrong results? IWhat  are you providing as a parameter, what result do you expect, and what are you getting instead? If you want help, **be specific** and provide the details you already have.

Comment: Agree with the above comment, however your first step to fixing this is almost certainly going to be to add an exception handler in your function even if it is just... Exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode || '  :  ' || sqlerrm);  This should give you some idea about where your error is happening.

Comment: @Shaun, you don't need an exception handler to see what the error is - since they have no handlers, any exception will get raised to the caller.

Comment: The first part of the code works. Oracle successfully creates the function. However, the following errors are received when trying to execute the function with the second part of the code:                                                     END
  *

ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp That is true, but this just allows it to finish and display the error nicely so would still be my first step in fixing this error, plus it is just good practice to have at minimum a when others to trap and log errors.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that you're missing the end-of-statement delimiter, in your case you need to add a semicolon and a slash to execute, e.g.:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (get_salary_byname('JEFF'));
END;
/
```